# Implementing authentication in uploaded files in java

Tags: java, spring, document-management

I have application where various files are uploaded in server. And the application has various users. Now, I want to implement authentication so that only privileged users can access to those uploaded documents. So, is there any document manager api in java to manage these documents. I have looked into alfresco, knowledgetree but those are separate applications. I want an api to implement in my application.

Comment: You may not get support unless you show some code and where you are stuck. Google may help you to know some of the APIs for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have enough information to suggest a solution, but I think that you can still think to use Alfresco if you embed it in your application.

Look at the following url: [Deployment options](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/deploy-options.html) that shows some deployment options.

Of course, this makes sense only if you need all the power of Alfresco.